# SQL Server Error: A timeout occurred while waiting for memory resources to execute the query in resource pool 'internal' (1). Rerun the query

Tags: sql-server

Some of my queries having Left joins and Unions were working perfectly till the data in my base tables crossed couple of thousand records.

Now the same queries in the stored procedures are raising timeout errors.

I am not sure whether to tweak the SQL queries from my side or do any memory settings on SQL server.

Error Text:

> A timeout occurred while waiting for memory resources to execute the
>   query in resource pool 'internal' (1). Rerun the query.
>
> 8/28/2018 7:15:50 AM Error: A timeout occurred while waiting for
>   memory resources to execute the query in resource pool 'internal' (1).
>   Rerun the query.    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception,
>   Boolean breakConnection, Action1 wrapCloseInAction)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException
>   exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject
>   stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior,
>   SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream,
>   BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject
>   stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryHasMoreRows(Boolean& moreRows) 
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryReadInternal(Boolean
>   setTimeout, Boolean& more)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.Read()    at
>   XXXXXX.Dal.Configuration.ConfigurationDAL.GetUsers(String
>   tenantConnectionString, Int32 entityId, Boolean includeUserGroups,
>   Int32 getUsersMode)

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/help/309256/how-to-troubleshoot-sql-server-error-8645

Comment: Thanks Mitch, i had to run DBCC commands to clear the sql cache.